# How to clean a MovieClip after a .addchild ? AS3/Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

im using .addchild to add an image to a movie clip:

```
function imageLoaded(e:Event):void {
    fn=fn+1;
    if (fn==1) { panel.estadoimg.addChild(imageLoader); loadImage(datosXML.localiza);}
    if (fn==2) { panel.mapa.mapaimg.addChild(imageLoader); fn=0; }
}
```

The think is that i want to reuse that movieclip, how can i clean it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you're adding images to two different containers in your example, but you would use **removeChildAt(0)** to get them out of there if the only thing in the movieclip is the image.  also remove any listeners associated with the image.  Null the image to offer it up for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

If `imageLoader` is the object you want to remove:

```
var p:DisplayObjectContainer = imageLoader.parent;
if (p)
  p.removeChild(imageLoader);

imageLoader = null;
```

Additionally, if `imageLoader` is of type `flash.display.Loader`, then you want to call `unload()` on it before cleaning it up. If it's Flex's `Image` or `SWFLoader` component, then you can just set the `source` property to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look at what casalib does with [casaMovieClip](http://as3.casalib.org/docs/org_casalib_display_CasaMovieClip.html). Usually I would use this library instead of adding these function, but it is good to have a peak at what's going on.
removeChild is ok, but without knowing what else is happening behind the scene and not completely destroying objects can cause memory leaks.

Given that you are using an image loader I'm assuming you already have at least one event listener. This event listener can be connected to your loaded image, and even if you remove this from the display list (through removeChild/removechildAt) you can still have the object lingering.